# Is this AMOLED screen damaged?

Tags: super-amoled

1. When i display a black screen on my phone, it is still brighter than when i turn it to sleep, is that how AMOLEDs normally behave (trying to "shine" the black darkness)?
2. When viewing the totally black screen (sadly dark gray screen) in dark, i see real black lines and dots on my display, see the picture i painted in mspaint. Is that a damaged screen? They dont show on turned-off display.
   *I think some old tamagotchi did this too :)*
3. [image: random black lines on gray display]
4. I read AMOLED can shut down pixels when displaying black (and save energy), can they do it after all, when they display gray anyway? Or is it the dimming that saves battery?

My phone is (should hopefuly be) Samsung Galaxy S III LTE (GT-I9305) so it should have AMOLED.

**EDIT** Ad. 2.: I googled a bit and it seems a common problem for all AMOLED screens. But since it is so hardly noticeable it isnt nothing to worry about. One poster summarizes it nicely here: http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/260791-amoled-black-dots-dark.html#post2726685

Comment: As regards your first point, it is normal on newer AMOLED screens. It was different on previous AMOLED generations with less resolution (black was real black). As regards your second point, please, could you make and post a photo of your screen?

Answer (score 1):

The screen is definitely damaged. The only solution is to replace it.

Comment: Thanks, but since you say definitely: The screen works normally, for example red screen is perfectly red everywhere. That image is just on totally black screen in total darkness.